# Print variables from Ansilbe host file in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Trying to fetch variable value in playbook, but is yielding to error as per below. Any suggestions to resolve variable?

Here is (eg dynamic ) inventory file ( where group name is not known in playbook )

```
$ cat ans_hosts
[gname_tools]
<machine_name_goes_here>
<machine_name_goes_here>
<machine_name_goes_here>

[gname_tools:vars]
group_name=gname_tools
clip_id=3
sub_id=a.b@c.com
```

Here is playbook

```
$ cat var_access.yml
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: Print Inventory variable
     shell: |
       cmd: |
         echo "{{hostvars['group_name']}}"
     register: ExcepStatus
     delegate_to: localhost

   - debug: msg="{{ExcepStatus.stdout}}"
```

Here is result of running playbook

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ans_hosts var_access.yml
PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print Inventory variable] *****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [<machine_name_goes_here> -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['group_name']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/gollip/ans/var_access.yml': line 7, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n   - name: Print Inventory variable\n     ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
<machine_name_goes_here>   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Could you clarify your goal? The play looks too overcomplicated to just print out a variable. `debug: var: group_name` should make the thing, there is no need to use shell or hostvars. Also, the inventory you've shared is a static one.

Answer (score 1):

[hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) is a dict of hosts, where each key is a dict of host variables. To fetch a variable from `hostvars`, you should first specify the host whose variables you want to access:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: hostvars['<machine_name_goes_here>']['group_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

For an inventory file

```ini
[test]
one.example.com
two.example.com

[test:vars]
MAIL=johndoe@example.com
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['MAIL'] }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names:
  - test
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names:
  - test

TASK [debug] ******************************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  msg: johndoe@example.com
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  msg: johndoe@example.com
```

Or in short

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ group_names | first }} and {{ MAIL }}"
```

will output

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  msg: test and johndoe@example.com
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  msg: test and johndoe@example.com
```

Comment: It's worth to point out that `group_names` is a special variable and that it lists all the groups that the host belongs to. A group variable value that the OP is asking about will be overridden by the last loaded group if a host belongs to multiple groups.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev, indeed. But for me it is not clear if such is necessary, a separate variable called `group_name` which contains the same value, the name of the group from inventory. With the currently available information from the OP it looked for me  redundant, unnecessary complex and trying to implement already available functionality, which is the reason why I've left it out.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev, regarding "_will be overridden by the last loaded group if a host belongs to multiple groups_", such isn't shown for me within the OP, therefore I've interpreted it in an other way. Maybe we'll get more information and depending on that we can interpret the question again.